# How do I print values from different levels of a multi-element JSON object into Google Sheets?

Tags: javascript, json, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have parsed the below JSON object using `var json = JSON.parse(ticket_orders)`, and now I'm trying to use Google Sheets script editor to make a table with four columns: **event_id**, **display** (from costs.base_price), **name** (from profile), and **status** (from barcodes, which is an array unlike the others).

The below JSON object shows only two elements, but I have 40 (but this is always changing). I am having trouble creating a function that iteratively extracts just the values I mentioned above and putting them neatly in a table in Google sheets.

```
var json = [{
          "team": null,             //This is the start of element 1
          "costs": {
            "base_price": {
              "display": "CA$0.00",
              "currency": "CAD",
              "value": 0,
              "major_value": "0.00"
            },
            "eventbrite_fee": {
              "display": "CA$0.00",
              "currency": "CAD",
              "value": 0,
              "major_value": "0.00"
            },
            "gross": {
              "display": "CA$0.00",
              "currency": "CAD",
              "value": 0,
              "major_value": "0.00"
            },
            "payment_fee": {
              "display": "CA$0.00",
              "currency": "CAD",
              "value": 0,
              "major_value": "0.00"
            },
            "tax": {
              "display": "CA$0.00",
              "currency": "CAD",
              "value": 0,
              "major_value": "0.00"
            }
          },
          "resource_uri": "https://www.eventbriteapi.com/v3/events/12345/attendees/12345/",
          "id": "12345",
          "changed": "2018-11-02T22:36:48Z",
          "created": "2018-11-02T19:07:24Z",
          "quantity": 1,
          "variant_id": null,
          "profile": {
            "first_name": "Kennedy",
            "last_name": "Singleton",
            "email": "kennedy@gmail.com",
            "name": "Kennedy Singleton",
            "addresses": {
              "home": {},
              "ship": {},
              "work": {},
              "bill": {},
              "fulfillment": {}
            }
          },
          "barcodes": [
            {
              "status": "used",
              "barcode": "1234567435234",
              "created": "2018-11-02T19:07:24Z",
              "changed": "2018-11-02T22:36:48Z",
              "checkin_type": 0,
              "checkin_method": "search",
              "is_printed": false
            }
          ],
          "answers": [],
          "checked_in": true,
          "cancelled": false,
          "refunded": false,
          "affiliate": null,
          "guestlist_id": null,
          "invited_by": null,
          "status": "Checked In",
          "ticket_class_name": "General Admission",
          "delivery_method": "electronic",
          "event_id": "12345",
          "order_id": "123123123",
          "ticket_class_id": "123123123"
        },
        {
          "team": null,             //This is the start of element 2
          "costs": {
            "base_price": {
              "display": "CA$0.00",
              "currency": "CAD",
              "value": 0,
              "major_value": "0.00"
            },
            "eventbrite_fee": {
              "display": "CA$0.00",
              "currency": "CAD",
              "value": 0,
              "major_value": "0.00"
            },
            "gross": {
              "display": "CA$0.00",
              "currency": "CAD",
              "value": 0,
              "major_value": "0.00"
            },
            "payment_fee": {
              "display": "CA$0.00",
              "currency": "CAD",
              "value": 0,
              "major_value": "0.00"
            },
            "tax": {
              "display": "CA$0.00",
              "currency": "CAD",
              "value": 0,
              "major_value": "0.00"
            }
          },
          "resource_uri": "https://www.eventbriteapi.com/v3/events/12345/attendees/12345/",
          "id": "12345",
          "changed": "2018-11-02T22:36:48Z",
          "created": "2018-11-02T19:07:24Z",
          "quantity": 1,
          "variant_id": null,
          "profile": {
            "first_name": "Kennedy",
            "last_name": "Singleton",
            "email": "kennedy@gmail.com",
            "name": "Kennedy Singleton",
            "addresses": {
              "home": {},
              "ship": {},
              "work": {},
              "bill": {},
              "fulfillment": {}
            }
          },
          "barcodes": [
            {
              "status": "used",
              "barcode": "1234567435234",
              "created": "2018-11-02T19:07:24Z",
              "changed": "2018-11-02T22:36:48Z",
              "checkin_type": 0,
              "checkin_method": "search",
              "is_printed": false
            }
          ],
          "answers": [],
          "checked_in": true,
          "cancelled": false,
          "refunded": false,
          "affiliate": null,
          "guestlist_id": null,
          "invited_by": null,
          "status": "Checked In",
          "ticket_class_name": "General Admission",
          "delivery_method": "electronic",
          "event_id": "12345",
          "order_id": "123123123",
          "ticket_class_id": "123123123"
        }]
```

Can you please help me create a function to accomplishes this?

I attempted to Google this but I couldn't find a Q&A that has the three parts of: 1) targeting values in different levels of the JSON object hierarchy, 2) having multiple elements that need to be iterated through, and 3) putting them into a Google Sheets table.

Here's what I've been able to script so far:

```
function getAndInsertConent(url) {
    const makeService = getApiService(); //Authorizes my access to the API via OAuth
    const apiFetechedContent = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url,{
        headers: {
            Authorization: 'Bearer ' + makeService.getAccessToken()
                 }
            });
    const content = apiFetechedContent.getContentText(); //Makes the raw, fetched JSON response accessible
    const json = JSON.parse(content); //Turns the JSON into a JavaScript object
    
    var rows = [Object.keys(json)]; // Retrieve headers, but this equals ['pagination', 'attendees']
    
    var jsonAttendees = json.attendees //stores just the 'attendees' branch of the JavaScript object
    
    //Store our target spreadsheet into a variable
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheets = ss.getSheets();
    var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
    
    //code to access the specific values I need
}
```

I couldn't get farther than than where I made that last comment in my code. I don't know how to access the values and put them neatly into a table.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you very much.

Comment: Can you add what you have already attempted?   Here are some references to get you started - 1) Here is an introduction to objects and key:value pairs. https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_objects.asp.   2) Introduction to For Loops.  When I started out, I founds that For/In was easier to wrap my head around https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_for.asp   3) Google App Script is based on Javascript, but it has specific functions to work within Sheets.  https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets - The part that took me the longest to understand is that Sheets ranges are 2D arrays.

Comment: @KrispinMiller Hi, yes, I've added my code. Thank you for those references. I read through them and they make sense but I'm really struggling with apply the theory to my own problem. Do you think you can look at my code and help me?

Answer (score 3):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to retrieve the values of `event_id, display (from costs.base_price), name (from profile), and status (from barcodes, which is an array unlike the others)`. from the value of `json`.
- You want to put the retrieved values to the Spreadsheet.
- You want to achieve this using Google Apps Script.

From your sample value of `json`, I thought that the structure of each element of JSON data including the array is always same. I thought that this might be able to be used. So, in order to retrieve the how about using `map()` and the destructuring assignment? When your script is modified, it becomes as follows.

#### Sample script:

Please set the sheet name you want to put the values.

```
function getAndInsertConent(url) {
  const sheetName = "Sheet1"; // Please set the sheet name.

  const makeService = getApiService();
  const apiFetechedContent = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, { headers: { Authorization: 'Bearer ' + makeService.getAccessToken() } });
  const content = apiFetechedContent.getContentText();
  const json = JSON.parse(content);

  const values = json.map(({ event_id, costs: { base_price: { display } }, profile: { name }, barcodes: [{ status }] }) => [event_id, display, name, status]);
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetName);
  sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1, values.length, values[0].length).setValues(values);
}
```

- **This script supposes that `json` of `const json = JSON.parse(content);` is the same with `json` of your sample value in your question. Please be careful this.**

  - If `jsonAttendees` is the same with `json` of your sample value in your question, please modify above script.
- In this script, the retrieved values are appended to the sheet. When you want to put the values to the specific range, please modify above script.

#### Note:

- When `values` of above script is checked, the following test script can be used.

  ```js
      const json = [{
        "team": null,             //This is the start of element 1
        "costs": {
          "base_price": {
            "display": "CA$0.00",
            "currency": "CAD",
            "value": 0,
            "major_value": "0.00"
          },
          "eventbrite_fee": {
            "display": "CA$0.00",
            "currency": "CAD",
            "value": 0,
            "major_value": "0.00"
          },
          "gross": {
            "display": "CA$0.00",
            "currency": "CAD",
            "value": 0,
            "major_value": "0.00"
          },
          "payment_fee": {
            "display": "CA$0.00",
            "currency": "CAD",
            "value": 0,
            "major_value": "0.00"
          },
          "tax": {
            "display": "CA$0.00",
            "currency": "CAD",
            "value": 0,
            "major_value": "0.00"
          }
        },
        "resource_uri": "https://www.eventbriteapi.com/v3/events/12345/attendees/12345/",
        "id": "12345",
        "changed": "2018-11-02T22:36:48Z",
        "created": "2018-11-02T19:07:24Z",
        "quantity": 1,
        "variant_id": null,
        "profile": {
          "first_name": "Kennedy",
          "last_name": "Singleton",
          "email": "kennedy@gmail.com",
          "name": "Kennedy Singleton",
          "addresses": {
            "home": {},
            "ship": {},
            "work": {},
            "bill": {},
            "fulfillment": {}
          }
        },
        "barcodes": [
          {
            "status": "used",
            "barcode": "1234567435234",
            "created": "2018-11-02T19:07:24Z",
            "changed": "2018-11-02T22:36:48Z",
            "checkin_type": 0,
            "checkin_method": "search",
            "is_printed": false
          }
        ],
        "answers": [],
        "checked_in": true,
        "cancelled": false,
        "refunded": false,
        "affiliate": null,
        "guestlist_id": null,
        "invited_by": null,
        "status": "Checked In",
        "ticket_class_name": "General Admission",
        "delivery_method": "electronic",
        "event_id": "12345",
        "order_id": "123123123",
        "ticket_class_id": "123123123"
      },
      {
        "team": null,             //This is the start of element 2
        "costs": {
          "base_price": {
            "display": "CA$0.00",
            "currency": "CAD",
            "value": 0,
            "major_value": "0.00"
          },
          "eventbrite_fee": {
            "display": "CA$0.00",
            "currency": "CAD",
            "value": 0,
            "major_value": "0.00"
          },
          "gross": {
            "display": "CA$0.00",
            "currency": "CAD",
            "value": 0,
            "major_value": "0.00"
          },
          "payment_fee": {
            "display": "CA$0.00",
            "currency": "CAD",
            "value": 0,
            "major_value": "0.00"
          },
          "tax": {
            "display": "CA$0.00",
            "currency": "CAD",
            "value": 0,
            "major_value": "0.00"
          }
        },
        "resource_uri": "https://www.eventbriteapi.com/v3/events/12345/attendees/12345/",
        "id": "12345",
        "changed": "2018-11-02T22:36:48Z",
        "created": "2018-11-02T19:07:24Z",
        "quantity": 1,
        "variant_id": null,
        "profile": {
          "first_name": "Kennedy",
          "last_name": "Singleton",
          "email": "kennedy@gmail.com",
          "name": "Kennedy Singleton",
          "addresses": {
            "home": {},
            "ship": {},
            "work": {},
            "bill": {},
            "fulfillment": {}
          }
        },
        "barcodes": [
          {
            "status": "used",
            "barcode": "1234567435234",
            "created": "2018-11-02T19:07:24Z",
            "changed": "2018-11-02T22:36:48Z",
            "checkin_type": 0,
            "checkin_method": "search",
            "is_printed": false
          }
        ],
        "answers": [],
        "checked_in": true,
        "cancelled": false,
        "refunded": false,
        "affiliate": null,
        "guestlist_id": null,
        "invited_by": null,
        "status": "Checked In",
        "ticket_class_name": "General Admission",
        "delivery_method": "electronic",
        "event_id": "12345",
        "order_id": "123123123",
        "ticket_class_id": "123123123"
      }];

      const values = json.map(({ event_id, costs: { base_price: { display } }, profile: { name }, barcodes: [{ status }] }) => [event_id, display, name, status]);
      console.log(values);
  ```
- If above sample script was not useful and the structure of each element of JSON data including the array is NOT always same, can you provide more sample values?

#### References:

- [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
- [Destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

Comment: Thank you! I'm just encountering one problem. When I'm using the mapping function, I get the error: "TypeError: json.map is not a function". When I used typeOf, json appeared to be an "Object", which is due to the parsing. It seems the map() function doesn't work on objects. Is there another map() function for objects like this?

Comment: @Nixu Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. Although I have already been mentioned in my answer, this my proposed script supposes that `json` of `const json = JSON.parse(content);` in your script is the same with `json` of your sample value in your question. From your replying, I'm worry that `const json = JSON.parse(content);` might be different from your sample value. How about this?

Comment: @Nixu If `json` of your sample value in your question is `var jsonAttendees = json.attendees`, please modify my script from `json.map(({,,,` to `json.attendees.map(({,,,` and test it again. If you cannot understand my English, please provide the value of `json` of `const json = JSON.parse(content);` in your current script?